# Derivative\Jacobian Matrix of $f:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, cross-product

I am working with the derivative of the cross-product of two vectors, and am trying to understand what the Jacobian matrix of derivatives would look like. In particular, I am confused about the size.

We have $f:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ as the cross product function. Would the Jacobian matrix of $Df(x,y,z)$ be a $3\times 3$ or a $3\times 6$ sized matrix? I guess this boils down to how I interpret $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: If $f$ is given by the cross product of two elements of $\mathbb R^3$, how is it a function of three variables, as you imply by writing $Df(x,y,z)$?

Comment: @amd My two input vectors are functions of x,y,z

Comment: So it seems that you’re really looking for is the Jacobian matrix of the function $\phi:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ given by $f(x,y,z)=v_1(x,y,z)\times v_2(x,y,z)$. That’s going to be $3\times3$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a $3\times 6$ matrix. I don't know how you can interpret $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$ and decide it's just $\Bbb R^3$. :)

Comment: Thank you, that was my thought exactly but I just wanted to make sure.